# Display column subset of DataTable in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I am creating a `DataTable` to store information for my project, which will later push information into a MS Excel file. I want to show the user some of this data in my WinForms project through a `DataGridView` control, but I do not want to show the user the entire `DataTable` - just essential columns. I've found this to be a challenge since `DataTable` is set up to work with rows more than columns.

I've tried to copy across from one DataTable to another, using one for storage and a subset for display, but due to columns sharing references, I either can't have multiple columns with the same name, or I alter the columns in one `DataTable` which subsequently changes both. I've also tried creating a subset table with `DataView`, but had the same problems.

Is there a clean way to go about this?
(Otherwise I'll just do it rough and try to set my column sizes so that unnecessary data can't be seen in the DataGridView.)

Comment: Can't you just set `AutoGenerateColumns=False` and then specify the databinding columns?

Comment: @clb9355, we hope that your issue has been resolved. May I suggest some further reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work... regards...

Comment: @Monty Not to worry, I know how accepting an answer works :) this task has been lower on my priority list in the last few days and I haven't been able to 100% get things working yet - the suggested solutions are definitely the right avenue for me to investigate, but don't entirely solve the issue (I believe I need to bind data to the columns, is all). I just want to be certain before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the columns (you want to show) in designer view. And set the property AutoGenerateColumns to false

Answer (score 0):

Try this

To hide Columns...

```
this.DataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

or you could filter the data from one datatable into another...

```
string[] colnames = new string[] { "col1", "col2" };
dt2 = dt1.DefaultView.ToTable(false, colnames);
```

I've not tested any of that code....

You could just fill another DataTable selecting only the Columns that you want from you data source....